# Mac Messages client user ID \20 connecting to Openfire

Tags: macos, xmpp, message

When I connect to the Openfire server using Messages client from Mac OS all users appear with "\20" instead of space, other clients like Spark doesnt have this problem, I have research and found out that this is something on the client, its how to escape the node part of the JID, is there a work arround to avoid having all users to appear with a "\20" instead of example: "john doe" , whenever there is a user with space it appears as "john\20doe"

I found this documentation http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0106.html#escaping

Thanks